# Possible to simulate click event on Dialog window of Browser?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

I know that the dialog(showMessage) is a closed API and that you can not force a click event on Dialog with any web-based technologies such as jQuery or Javascript. The instance of the window within the browser is single threaded and locks the thread until the dialog receives an event. This I understand.

What I am trying to do is simulate a click event pragmatically for Test Case purposes. I am using the Telerik testing framework to run these Test Cases in C# .NET 4.5 environment.

So is it possible to simulate this click event? It is testing the behavior of one our buttons that when clicked the user must confirm they are leaving the page without saving changes.

Thanks to all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Telerik's testing tools, but as far as i know the only way to "issue" such a click would be with a ui macro that automated mouse motions and actually clicked the screen at a particular location.

That said, you may be able to solve your problem by using a mocked method. Rather than directly calling window.prompt, instead define your own prompt function along the lines of:

```
debug = true; //remove or set to false when not testing

var myPrompt = function(){
  if(debug){
    return "Greetings, Program";
  } else {
    return prompt("Please enter your greeting:","Greeting");
  }
}
```

You can naturally set this up for other types of message box, so long as you keep the type they return in mind.